# Should I raise an exception when getting the size or the position of a file?

Tags: windows, api, delphi

I'm trying to make a class in Delphi that handles files. I have a property that returns the size of the file and another one that returns the position of the file. I don't know if any error can happen with these calls. Should I raise an exception?

My code is:

```
function TFile.GetSize: Int64;
var
  FileSizeHi, FileSizeLo: Cardinal;
begin
  FileSizeLo := GetFileSize(FHandle, @FileSizeHi);
  if (FileSizeLo = INVALID_FILE_SIZE) and (GetLastError = NO_ERROR) then
    Result := $FFFFFFFF
  else
    Result := FileSizeLo or Int64(FileSizeHi) shl 32;
end;

function TFile.GetPosition: Int64;
var
  FilePosHi, FilePosLo: Cardinal;
begin
  FilePosHi := 0;
  FilePosLo := 0;
  FilePosLo := SetFilePointer(FHandle, FilePosLo, @FilePosHi, FILE_CURRENT);
  if (FilePosLo = INVALID_SET_FILE_POINTER) and (GetLastError = NO_ERROR) then
    Result := $FFFFFFFF
  else
    Result := FilePosLo or Int64(FilePosHi) shl 32;
end;
```

I don't know what error could happen when I call GetFileSize or SetFilePointer (without moving the file pointer).

Comment: You can also use [`Int64Rec`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/System.SysUtils.Int64Rec) to do right away `Int64Rec(Result).Lo:= GetFileSize( FHandle, @Int64Rec(Result).Hi );` and/or `if Int64Rec(Result).Lo= MAXDWORD` without any intermediate variables.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, errors can happen with those functions, so I would recommend raising an exception, otherwise the caller doesn't know if it has received an invalid value or not, as `$FFFFFFFF` is a valid size/position for 64bit values. Perhaps you meant to use `-1` (`$FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF`) instead?

However, whether you raise an exception or not, your `GetLastError()` check is wrong. It needs to use `<>` instead of `=`. When the file function returns `$FFFFFFFF` for the low value, `GetLastError()` will return 0 when the low value really is `$FFFFFFFF`, otherwise `GetLastError()` will return non-zero when the low/high values are invalid.

Try this:

```
function TFile.GetSize: Int64;
var
  FileSizeHi, FileSizeLo: DWORD;
begin
  FileSizeLo := GetFileSize(FHandle, @FileSizeHi);
  if (FileSizeLo = INVALID_FILE_SIZE) and (GetLastError <> NO_ERROR) then
    RaiseLastOSError // or: Result := -1
  else
    Result := FileSizeLo or (Int64(FileSizeHi) shl 32);
end;

function TFile.GetPosition: Int64;
var
  FilePosHi, FilePosLo: DWORD;
begin
  FilePosHi := 0;
  FilePosLo := 0;
  FilePosLo := SetFilePointer(FHandle, FilePosLo, @FilePosHi, FILE_CURRENT);
  if (FilePosLo = INVALID_SET_FILE_POINTER) and (GetLastError <> NO_ERROR) then
    RaiseLastOSError // or: Result := -1
  else
    Result := FilePosLo or (Int64(FilePosHi) shl 32);
end;
```

On a side note, consider using [`GetFileSizeEx()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-getfilesizeex) and [`SetFilePointerEx()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-setfilepointerex) instead, as they operate on 64bit values without breaking them up into low/high parts.

Comment: No. The Win API documentation says that if the return value is INVALID_FILE_SIZE/INVALID_SET_FILE_POINTER then you have to check GetLastError. If it's NO_ERROR, it means that the file size/file position is 0xFFFFFFFF. Otherwise it's a real error so you have to raise an exception in that case. Anyway, thanks for the info!

Comment: @WolfWestern No, it only means the lower 32 bits are `$FFFF FFFF` and you truncate it to that, ignoring what the upper 32 bits may hold. A filesize can also be `$2 FFFF FFFF` and thanks to your logic the function will only return `$FFFF FFFF`.

Comment: @WolfWestern what I said is not wrong. Look at your original logic. If low is returned as $FFFFFFFF and GetLastError() returns NO_ERROR (0), you were treating that as a failure instead of a success. The code in my answer treats it as a failure properly.